# Bash: /usr/bin/pip: Permission denied

Tags: python, bash, unix, pip, path

For a couple of days now I have been trying to set up a shared server to be able to install the python FLASK module. I have looked through a lot of topics on this subject but still run into problems. I'm connecting to SSH over PuTTY without sudo. Here's what i tried to do and what i get:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1

which pip
which: no pip in (/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/.local/bin:/.local/bin:/home/<user>/.local/bin)

whereis pip
pip: /home/<user>/.local/bin/pip /home/<user>/.local/bin/pip3.7 /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz

export PATH=$PATH:~/home/<user>/.local/bin
pip install --user flask
-bash: /usr/bin/pip: Permission denied

cd /home/<user>/.local/bin
pip install flask
-bash: /usr/bin/pip: Permission denied

echo $PATH 
/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/.local/bin:/.local/bin:/home/serwer2134706/.local/bin

stat /usr/bin/pip
  File: /usr/bin/pip
  Size: 216             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 9312h/37650d    Inode: 131245      Links: 2
Access: (0110/---x--x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-10-21 08:36:12.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2020-10-20 12:25:03.000000000 +0200
Change: 2021-02-17 16:52:09.000000000 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Do you have any idea how to bite it?

Comment: Show `stat /usr/bin/pip`. Don't you want `export PATH=/home/<user>/.local/bin/:$PATH`?

Comment: I edited the post and added a `stat`.

Comment: `---x--x---` well, surely you wouldn't be able to execute it. But you want to use `/usr/bin/pip` or your `/home/../local/bin/pip`? Make sure proper path is first. And fix those permissions..

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:
`export PATH=$PATH:~/home/<user>/.local/bin`

This will expand to `/home/<user>/home/<user>/.local/bin` which does not exist.

You need to drop the `~` before `/home/<user>/.local/bin` as you are already specifying the absolute path.

Also, print and check `echo $PATH` to verify it is correctly set.

Comment: `echo $PATH` --->
`/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/.local/bin:/.local/bin:/home/serwer2134706/.local/bin`